# Need create a database query which would give me records having column value having '=sr_pg_1?k=' this pattern anywhere in the URL column

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Example:

```
https://www.example.edu/s?k=d%26d+3.5&page=2&qid=1637866766&ref=sr_pg_1?k=d%26d+3.5
```

I need to find out the records from snowflake having column values having substrings or pattern `like '=sr_pg_1?k='`

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can do it the exact way you described:

```
select url from your_table where url like '%=sr\_pg\_1?k=%';
```

You need to watch out [what characters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) to escape using `\` or a custom `ESCAPE` character definition. In your case, you need to escape both underscores `_`.

Comment: Be careful, because your plain pattern works by coincidence. [LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) pattern matching syntax accepts any character in palce of `_`, so `=sr!pg!1?k=` could also match. I updated my answer to reflect that and escape them.